# Apache2 redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com with vhosts

Tags: apache, http, web, mod-rewrite, https

Folks,

I have apache server with vhosts.

For vhosts, I need to redirect `http://*.example.com` to `https://*.example.com` and it works as last block in the code.

Reg. the main server, I want to redirect `https://example.com`, `http://example.com` & `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

`http://example.com` & `http://www.example.com` works fine but only `https://example.com` not directing.

Any ideas ?!

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com #(NOT WORKING)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com [R=301,L]


# Redirect http://example.com to https://www.example.com  #(WORKING)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]


# Redirects http://*.example.com to https://*.example.com #(WORKING)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Lemme know if my answer works. Probably should :D

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

Happy Cod3ing!

Comment: @Nurhun It must actually work. What directory is port 443  configured to? Do http and HTTPS display different pages?

Comment: @Nurhun can you please paste your virtualhost config here, in your question.